# Cut and paste part of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using my own tags. They start with `[` and end with `]`.

I would like to sort the tags. So instead of

```
[TITLE|prefix=test][DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1|reverse=0][STORENAME|prefix=SHOP]
```

it should be

```
[DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1|reverse=0][TITLE|prefix=test][STORENAME|prefix=SHOP]
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
const tag = 'DYNAMIC'
const str = '[TITLE|prefix=test][DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1|reverse=0][STORENAME|prefix=SHOP]';
const regex = new RegExp(`\\[${tag}[^\\[]+`, 'g');
console.log(str.replace(regex, ''));
```

So the tag `[DYNAMIC]` has been removed, which is good but it should be also placed at the beginning of the string. How can I do this?

Comment: Following which sorting algorithm? Why is TITLE and not STORENAME the second tag in the list? Do you need to do it with regular expressions?

Comment: You should convert this string to an array or object and sort them instead, and then join their elements

Comment: @Diego it should be my own sorting algorithm. So the goal is not the alphabetical sort.

Comment: Do you have a specific requirement to manipulate the string using Regular Expressions for this? If so you may want to investigate something like capture groups (https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups).

Although, the easiest method, and not to mention the most readable for other developers, is to split the string on a particular character, then rearrange the elements of the Array or Object you are left with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivial if you want alphabetical sort

```js
let  str =  `[TITLE|prefix=test][DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1|reverse=0][STORENAME|prefix=SHOP]`
str = str.split("[").sort().join("[")
console.log(str)
```

If you want a fixed order

```js
const sortArr = ["DYNAMIC","TITLE","STORENAME"];

let  str =  `[TITLE|prefix=test][DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1|reverse=0][STORENAME|prefix=SHOP]`
str = str.split("[")
  .sort((a, b) => sortArr.indexOf(a.split("|")[0]) - sortArr.indexOf(b.split("|")[0]))
  .join("[")
console.log(str)
```